# Wordpress. Вывести страницу как пост

Tags: wordpress

Есть материал, который находится на странице, но он необходим также и внутри одной категории. Очевидный выход это создать пост с содержанием страницы, но это будет дублирование. Как я могу интегрировать страницу в категорию, чтобы она отображалась, будто она пост?
Возможно создать заглушку поста с картинкой и описанием, но без контента, а при открытии редирект на страницу. Но это как-то не лаконично.

Comment: Созать пост, удалить страницу.

Comment: Это первое, что пришло в голову, но этот вариант не подходит. Страница должна остаться страницей. Но спасибо.

Comment: Это говорит о неправильном понимании и построении структуры контента. Но комменты на SO - не то место, чтобы выяснять "что хочется" и давать советы "как надо".

Comment: Архитектура действительно "уникальная", но не выполнять задачу из-за этого это не наша дорога. Если у Вас возникнет дельная идея, которая поможет решить поставленную именно таким образом задачу, я ее с удовольствием рассмотрю.

Comment: Идею я озвучил - надо сделать правильное строение структуры контента. Но много не известных. Даже не объяснено почему не подходит первоначальное предложение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет просто указать id этой страницы и показать ее контент там где требуется?

```
$post_id=1257; 
$post = get_post($post_id); 
$content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 
echo $content;
```

Comment: А я смогу страницу по id добавить в вывод категории фильтром? 
Выводится категория:
пост 1, пост 2, страница, пост 3

Comment: Не, кажется так не выйдет.

Comment: Почему нет. Я только что вывел контент страницы в категории с постами.

Comment: У меня вышло будто идут превьюшки постов, а потом, вне вывода категорий, пошел контент страницы. Мне кажется что нужно каким - то образом создать превьюшку для страницы, применить к ней css как у превьюшек постов и поместить после вывода постов тем способом, который Вы посоветовали. Пока мозгую, но Вы помогли с направлением.

Comment: В $post я так понимаю уже есть все необходимое для превью поста? Название, текст и картинка, собственно.

Comment: Да, все что угодно можно вытащить и автора и аватарку автора, все что относится к странице с указанным id,

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_post подробнее здесь

Comment: После того, как я сделал вывод через get_post, мне понадобилось вывести название категории, которой у страницы нет. Я решил зайти в редактор страницы и поставить галочку на нужную категорию. После этого пост в категории продублировался, т.к вордпресс ВЫВОДИТ СТРАНИЦЫ КАК ПОСТЫ ИЗ КОРОБКИ, без костылей :)

Answer (score 0):

В редакторе страницы в правом боковом меню есть **чекбоксы с категориями**, который применяются к странице. Если назначить странице необходимую категорию, она начнет выводиться в ней наряду с постами. Родными средствами wordpress

Comment: А можно скриншот как выглядит выбор категорий у страниц?

Comment: Можно. Куда кинуть?
Создание страницы => снизу справа Categories => Search Categories

Comment: Новый сайт делаю, категории добавить нельзя в этом месте. Вывод - это либо плагин, либо тема позволяла. Тогда get_post() отличное решение.